# Как вывести наибольшее значение (не массив, пока что) js.jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

сравнить значение в msq2 и msq3
"Код" вот такой html

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 offset-md-0">  
    <div class="form-group">  
        <span>Единая Ставка</span>  
        <div id="TamStav"></div>  
        <div id="TamStav2"></div>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

js

```
var msq2 = '';
var msq3 = '';
if (CarType === 100 && face === 888 && rad === 3 && engine_capacityy >= 0 && price_buy_car_total <= 8500) 
{ 
    msq = duty + mass_ff + power + price_buy_car_total + (engine_capacityy * 2.5); 
    msq2 = engine_capacityy * (2.5 * 79.55) + (text0 + text1); 
    msq3 = ((price_buy_car_total * 54) / 100) * 68.14; 
}
var $total_msq2 = $('#TamStav').html(msq2);
var $total_msq3 = $('#TamStav2').html(msq3);
```

Простите за код...и спасибо если подскажете, просто там много таких строчек.

Comment: Совсем не ясно что к чему. Опишите, пожалуйста, конкретнее, что Вы пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: if parseInt(msq2) < parseInt(msq3) { ... } ? или я вас не понял(

Comment: @entithat к примеру если число в msq3 будет больше, то оно должно выводится в  <div id="TamStav2"></div>, в то время как msq2 которое будет меньше, не должно выводится. Простите, просто я сам только начал изучение.

Comment: @Haswell я тебя люблю! Спасибо!!!! Буду должен!)